# Where to Put CSS in mandrill template

Tags: css, mailchimp, mandrill

I was using mandrill for sending mails . Using mandrill template functionality, i have properly coded on server side to send the mails. I am receiving the mails, but CSS is not properly rendered. In my code i have set inline_CSS = 'true'. Also, in Mandrill in settings-> sending options i have set 'Inline CSS Styles In HTML Emails' = true. But still when i design a template its not rendered properly in 'preview and test' and also if send via API.

In Addition to this, i need to know how to add CSS file to your template dir. OR how to give the link to this CSS file. Because doing the settings is ok, but there should be some place where i need to put that file or pass it some way.

Comment: yes i am including the CSS like this in template code(html/css) `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="zooeck.css"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Zooeck</title>
</head>`

Comment: you should include the actual css, not a link to the css. 
You are using an external/linked stylesheet. That does not work for mail. You need Inline style is like this: `<head><style>
hr {color:sienna;}
p {margin-left:20px;}
body {background-image:url("images/back40.gif");}
</style>
</head>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mail clients cannot load style content from an externally-linked stylesheet. There is no local file path/system, so all style must be included within the template itself, between `<style>` tags.